# How to plot some graph with labels?(pyqtgraph/other)

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I try to plot some square:
A (0,0)
B (0,1)
C (1,1)
D (1,0)

Its easy in using the pyqtgraph:

```py
    plt = pg.plot([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], pen=None, symbol='o')
    plt.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
```

But how to add labels (like A,B,C,D)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setLabel as below :

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
plt = pg.plot([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], pen=None, symbol='o')
plt.setLabel('left', "A")
plt.setLabel('bottom', "B")
plt.setLabel('right', "C")
plt.setLabel('top', "D")
plt.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
```